# Mule - Track Order (Tshirt Service) returning Malformed JSON?

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio

I am sending a request to the Mulesoft tshirt service to track the order.
I am sending a JSON request via Postman (Chrome) and I am getting a error returned in Postman: Malformed JSON.

But there is nothing in the Mulesoft Studio console.

Mulesoft Flow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd">
    <ws:consumer-config doc:name="Web Service Consumer" name="Web_Service_Consumer" port="TshirtServicePort" service="TshirtService" serviceAddress="http://tshirt-service.cloudhub.io" wsdlLocation="tshirt.wsdl"/>
    <data-mapper:config doc:name="xml_listinventoryresponse__to_json" name="xml_listinventoryresponse__to_json" transformationGraphPath="xml_listinventoryresponse__to_json.grf"/>
    <data-mapper:config doc:name="xml_ordertshirtresponse__to_json" name="xml_ordertshirtresponse__to_json" transformationGraphPath="xml_ordertshirtresponse__to_json.grf"/>
    <data-mapper:config doc:name="string_to_xml_authenticationheader_" name="string_to_xml_authenticationheader_" transformationGraphPath="string_to_xml_authenticationheader_.grf"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="JSON_To_Xml_OrderTshirt_" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml_ordertshirt_.grf" doc:name="JSON_To_Xml_OrderTshirt_"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="JSON_To_Xml_TrackOrder_" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml_trackorder_.grf" doc:name="JSON_To_Xml_TrackOrder_"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="XML_To_JSON" transformationGraphPath="xml_to_json.grf" doc:name="XML_To_JSON"/>



<flow name="OrderTracking" doc:name="OrderTracking">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8001" path="orderTracking" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<data-mapper:transform config-ref="JSON_To_Xml_TrackOrder_" doc:name="JSON To Xml<TrackOrder>"/>
<ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="TrackOrder" doc:name="TrackOrder"/>
<data-mapper:transform config-ref="XML_To_JSON" doc:name="XML To JSON"/>
<http:response-builder status="200" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
</flow>

</mule>
```

JSON request

```
{
  "email":"info8001@mulesoft.com",
  "orderId":"264"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears your JSON request it not proper. 
The JSON you provided when converted to XML will be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<email>info8001@mulesoft.com</email>
<orderId>264</orderId>
```

Which is not complete as there is no root element to enclose the data in the XML.

Try modifying your JSON and see if it works.

Comment: Mule xml is written without the final xml, if I add the closing xml tag it gives error.